# Change background on changing month on calender using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically want to change the background color of the body on changing the month. Like if it is January then red color, if February then yellow and so on. I tried doing using javascript but didn't work for me. 
need the solution as fast as possible.

```js
var monthArray = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
 

  function changeTable (){
   year = document.getElementById("yearC").textContent;
   month = monthArray.indexOf(document.getElementById("monthC").textContent);
   maxDays = new Date(year,month+1,0).getDate();
   startingDay = new Date(year,month,1).getDay();

   if(startingDay!=0){
    startingDay -=1;
   }else{
    startingDay = 6;
   }
   tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
   var date = 0;
   for(var i = 0;i<35;i++){
    tds[i].textContent='';
    tds[i].className = "";
   }

   for(var i = startingDay ;i<tds.length;i++){

    date += 1
    if(date>maxDays){
     break;
    }
    
    if(date<10){
     tds[i].textContent = '0'+(date);
    }
    else{
     tds[i].textContent = date;
    }
    if(parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())==year && parseInt(new Date().getMonth())==month&&parseInt(new Date().getDate())==date){
    
     tds[i].className = "today";
    
    }
   }
   var i = 0;
   while(maxDays>date){
    tds[i].textContent = date+1;
    date+=1;
    i+=1;
   }
   

    
  }
 function prevYear(){
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent)-1;
  changeTable();
 }
 function prevMonth(){
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent)
  if(i == 0){
   i = 11;
   text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
   text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent)-1;
  }else{
   i-=1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
  changeTable();

 }
 function nextMonth(){
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent)
  if(i == 11){
   i = 0;
   text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
   text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent)+1;
  }else{
   i+=1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
  changeTable();
 }
 function nextYear(){
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent)+1;
  changeTable();
 }
 yearP = document.getElementById("yearP");
 yearN = document.getElementById("yearN");
 monthP = document.getElementById("monthP");
 monthN = document.getElementById("monthN");
 yearP.addEventListener('click',prevYear);
 yearN.addEventListener('click',nextYear);
 monthN.addEventListener('click',nextMonth);
 monthP.addEventListener('click',prevMonth);
 
 function intial(){

 } 




month5 = document.getElementById("monthP");
function changeback (){
 if (month5 == 'January')
 {
    document.body.style.background = white;
}
 }
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
}
 #monthC{
  width: 139px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(15, 155, 15));
 }
 table{
  padding:10px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 4px solid green;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px black;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
 }
 th{
  padding: 10px;
  border:2px solid black;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: white;
 }
 tr{
  margin:0px;
 }
 td{
  padding:20px 10px;
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
 }
 td.today{
  padding:20px 10px;
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size:30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
 }
 .month{
  height: 50px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
 }
 button{
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:30px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>calendar</title>
</head>
<body> 
<table>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="7" class="month">
 <button id="monthP"> << </button>
 <button id="yearP"> < </button>
 <div id="monthC">January</div>'<span id="yearC">2017</span>
 <button id="yearN"> > </button>
 <button id="monthN"> >> </button>
 </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Monday</th>
 <th>Tuesday</th>
 <th>Wednesday</th>
 <th>Thursday</th>
 <th>Friday</th>
 <th>Saturday</th>
 <th>Sunday</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>30</td>
 <td>31</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>01</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>02</td>
 <td>03</td>
 <td>04</td>
 <td>05</td>
 <td>06</td>
 <td>07</td>
 <td>08</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>09</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>13</td>
 <td>14</td>
 <td>15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>16</td>
 <td>17</td>
 <td>18</td>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>20</td>
 <td>21</td>
 <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>23</td>
 <td>24</td>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>26</td>
 <td>27</td>
 <td>28</td>
 <td>29</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried implementing but it didn't change. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array of sample colors `colorArray`, and then use that array in a function that updates your background linear gradient like so:

```
function changeBgColor(index) {
  document.body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, '+colorArray[index]+','+colorArray[index+1]+')';
}
```

Place this function into your `prevMonth` and `nextMonth` functions and pass in the current index as an argument.

Try the **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/yogPOb)** or the snippet below:

```js
var colorArray = [
  "AliceBlue",
  "AntiqueWhite",
  "Aqua",
  "Aquamarine",
  "Azure",
  "Beige",
  "Bisque",
  "Black",
  "BlanchedAlmond",
  "Blue",
  "BlueViolet",
  "Brown",
  "BurlyWood"
];


var monthArray = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

function changeBgColor(index) {
  document.body.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + colorArray[index] + ',' + colorArray[index + 1] + ')';
}

function changeTable() {
  year = document.getElementById("yearC").textContent;
  month = monthArray.indexOf(document.getElementById("monthC").textContent);
  maxDays = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
  startingDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();

  if (startingDay != 0) {
    startingDay -= 1;
  } else {
    startingDay = 6;
  }
  tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
  var date = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    tds[i].textContent = "";
    tds[i].className = "";
  }

  for (var i = startingDay; i < tds.length; i++) {
    date += 1;
    if (date > maxDays) {
      break;
    }

    if (date < 10) {
      tds[i].textContent = "0" + date;
    } else {
      tds[i].textContent = date;
    }
    if (
      parseInt(new Date().getFullYear()) == year &&
      parseInt(new Date().getMonth()) == month &&
      parseInt(new Date().getDate()) == date
    ) {
      tds[i].className = "today";
    }
  }
  var i = 0;
  while (maxDays > date) {
    tds[i].textContent = date + 1;
    date += 1;
    i += 1;
  }
}

function prevYear() {
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent) - 1;
  changeTable();
}

function prevMonth() {
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent);
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 11;
    text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
    text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent) - 1;
  } else {
    i -= 1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
  changeBgColor(i)
  changeTable();
}

function nextMonth() {
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent);
  if (i == 11) {
    i = 0;
    text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
    text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent) + 1;
  } else {
    i += 1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
  changeBgColor(i)
  changeTable();
}

function nextYear() {
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent) + 1;
  changeTable();
}
yearP = document.getElementById("yearP");
yearN = document.getElementById("yearN");
monthP = document.getElementById("monthP");
monthN = document.getElementById("monthN");
yearP.addEventListener("click", prevYear);
yearN.addEventListener("click", nextYear);
monthN.addEventListener("click", nextMonth);
monthP.addEventListener("click", prevMonth);

function intial() {}

month5 = document.getElementById("monthP");

function changeback() {
  if (month5 == "January") {
    document.body.style.background = '#fff';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}

#monthC {
  width: 139px;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(15, 155, 15));
}

table {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 4px solid green;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px black;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  margin: 0px;
}

td {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
}

td.today {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}

.month {
  height: 50px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

button {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" class="month">
      <button id="monthP"> << </button>
      <button id="yearP"> < </button>
      <div id="monthC">January</div>'<span id="yearC">2017</span>
      <button id="yearN"> > </button>
      <button id="monthN"> >> </button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>01</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>04</td>
    <td>05</td>
    <td>06</td>
    <td>07</td>
    <td>08</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>09</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Update:**

You can use the same idea for background images.

Add this to your CSS:

```
background-image: url('https://placebear.com/1200/1200');
```

Then update your JavaScript with a `changeBgImage` function that uses an array of images:

```
var backgroundImages = [];

for(var i=1;i<13;i++){
  backgroundImages.push('https://placebear.com/1200/120'+i);
}
function changeBgImage(index) {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+backgroundImages[index]+')';
}
```

Place this `changeBgImage` function into your `prevMonth` and `nextMonth` functions and pass in the current index as an argument.

Background image change **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/prRdrr)**

Comment: thanx for your help, this is awesome .Can you do me one more favor about how to add images in background and change on changing the month?

Comment: @djmayank Sure - I just added an update to my answer on the bottom.

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

you can keep a variable to store current month, which you will update every time the month is changed then you must call your changeback() function every time you change the month. Also update the background with string literal 'white' not white which would be an undefined variable.

```js
var monthArray = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],currentMonth;     

  function changeTable (){
   year = document.getElementById("yearC").textContent;
   month = monthArray.indexOf(document.getElementById("monthC").textContent);
   maxDays = new Date(year,month+1,0).getDate();
   startingDay = new Date(year,month,1).getDay();

   if(startingDay!=0){
    startingDay -=1;
   }else{
    startingDay = 6;
   }
   tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
   var date = 0;
   for(var i = 0;i<35;i++){
    tds[i].textContent='';
    tds[i].className = "";
   }

   for(var i = startingDay ;i<tds.length;i++){

    date += 1
    if(date>maxDays){
     break;
    }
    
    if(date<10){
     tds[i].textContent = '0'+(date);
    }
    else{
     tds[i].textContent = date;
    }
    if(parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())==year && parseInt(new Date().getMonth())==month&&parseInt(new Date().getDate())==date){
    
     tds[i].className = "today";
    
    }
   }
   var i = 0;
   while(maxDays>date){
    tds[i].textContent = date+1;
    date+=1;
    i+=1;
   }
   

    
  }
 function prevYear(){
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent)-1;
  changeTable();
 }
 function prevMonth(){
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent)
  if(i == 0){
   i = 11;
   text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
   text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent)-1;
  }else{
   i-=1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
        currentMonth = monthArray[i];
  changeTable();
        changeback();
 }
 function nextMonth(){
  text = document.getElementById("monthC");
  var i = monthArray.indexOf(text.textContent)
  if(i == 11){
   i = 0;
   text1 = document.getElementById("yearC");
   text1.textContent = parseInt(text1.textContent)+1;
  }else{
   i+=1;
  }
  text.textContent = monthArray[i];
        currentMonth = monthArray[i];
  changeTable();
        changeback();
 }
 function nextYear(){
  text = document.getElementById("yearC");
  text.textContent = parseInt(text.textContent)+1;
  changeTable();
 }
 yearP = document.getElementById("yearP");
 yearN = document.getElementById("yearN");
 monthP = document.getElementById("monthP");
 monthN = document.getElementById("monthN");
 yearP.addEventListener('click',prevYear);
 yearN.addEventListener('click',nextYear);
 monthN.addEventListener('click',nextMonth);
 monthP.addEventListener('click',prevMonth);
 
 function intial(){

 } 




function changeback (){
 if (currentMonth == 'January')
 {
    document.body.style.background = 'white';
}
 }
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
}
 #monthC{
  width: 139px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(15, 155, 15));
 }
 table{
  padding:10px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 4px solid green;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px black;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
 }
 th{
  padding: 10px;
  border:2px solid black;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: white;
 }
 tr{
  margin:0px;
 }
 td{
  padding:20px 10px;
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color: #DAF7A6;
 }
 td.today{
  padding:20px 10px;
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  font-size:30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
 }
 .month{
  height: 50px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  background-color: green;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
 }
 button{
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:30px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>calendar</title>
</head>
<body> 
<table>
 <tr>
 <th colspan="7" class="month">
 <button id="monthP"> << </button>
 <button id="yearP"> < </button>
 <div id="monthC">January</div>'<span id="yearC">2017</span>
 <button id="yearN"> > </button>
 <button id="monthN"> >> </button>
 </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th>Monday</th>
 <th>Tuesday</th>
 <th>Wednesday</th>
 <th>Thursday</th>
 <th>Friday</th>
 <th>Saturday</th>
 <th>Sunday</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>30</td>
 <td>31</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>01</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>02</td>
 <td>03</td>
 <td>04</td>
 <td>05</td>
 <td>06</td>
 <td>07</td>
 <td>08</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>09</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>13</td>
 <td>14</td>
 <td>15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>16</td>
 <td>17</td>
 <td>18</td>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>20</td>
 <td>21</td>
 <td>22</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>23</td>
 <td>24</td>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>26</td>
 <td>27</td>
 <td>28</td>
 <td>29</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. There is no call for method changing background - it should be called on month change (add listener).
2. You have many missing semicolons - check it carefully.
3. Color should be write as string "white" not just white.
4. To get text value for month5 you should use ".textContent":

   month5 = document.getElementById("monthP").textContent;
5. You get month name from incorrect element, it should be from "monthC" not "monthP".